# Using Sql Server with Django in production

Tags: python, sql-server, django, pyodbc

Has anybody got recent experience with deploying a Django application with an SQL Server database back end? Our workplace is heavily invested in SQL Server and will not support Django if there isn't a sufficiently developed back end for it.

I'm aware of mssql.django-pyodbc and django-mssql as unofficially supported back ends. Both projects seem to have only one person contributing which is a bit of a worry though the contributions seem to be somewhat regular.

Are there any other back ends for SQL Server that are well supported? Are the two I mentioned here 'good enough' for production? What are your experiences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below **official Microsoft package** to connect the SQL server to Django.

```
pip install mssql-django
```

**Settings**

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'user@myserver',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'myserver.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}

# set this to False if you want to turn off pyodbc's connection pooling
DATABASE_CONNECTION_POOLING = False
```

**More Information**: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django

Answer (score 22):

As has been stated, django-pyodbc is a good way to go.  PyODBC is probably the most mature SQL Server library for Python there is.

The only thing you may have problems with is that pyodbc doesn't support stored procedures very well (you can call them, but you have no way to get results from them).  You *can* call them using pymssql, but I would avoid it if at all possible as it doesn't support the standard DB-API interface and may be subject to changes.  If you need to do this, your best bet is to use [adodbapi](http://adodbapi.sourceforge.net/) directly (it's included with the python win32 package, which you'll probably end up installing anyway).

Comment: django-mssql uses a fork of adodbapi and supports stored procedures.

Comment: You can get the results from SQLServer stored procedures by calling them like so: `cursor.execute('DECLARE @results int;EXEC @results=spMyProc;SELECT @results')`

Comment: Update: Using Django 2.0+ I had success with [django-pyodbc-azure](https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/) but not django-pyodbc.

Answer (score 19):

These days

- [django-mssql](https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/): resulted in error "NoneType not callable" upon `./manage.py migrate`
- [avidal/django-pyodbc](https://github.com/avidal/django-pyodbc): unmaintained. Replaced by:

  - [django-pyodbc](https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/): no support for python 3
  - [django-pyodbc-azure](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/tree/master): works for me so far

    - EDIT: Seems to be unmaintained. Filed [issue 125](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/issues/125#issuecomment-350962115) asking about status
    - EDIT: got reply from maintainer. Will be made up-to-date with Django 2.0 soon
    - EDIT: maintainer released version 2.0 for django 2.0
    - EDIT: maintainer released version 2.1 for django 2.1

EDIT: Here are the package versions

```
Django==1.11.6
django-mssql==1.8
pyodbc==4.0.19
django-pyodbc==1.1.1
django-pyodbc-azure==1.11.0.0
```

Comment: it'd be helpful to provide versions of Django and the libraries you tested, because this information could become quickly out of date.

Comment: Also note that `django-pyodbc` and its forks run on Linux--unlike `django-mssql`, it has no Windows dependencies.  SQL Server doesn't even require Windows anymore, so that will probably become increasingly relevant in the future.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a "modern" answer to this question.  I successfully deployed Django 1.11 on a production Ubuntu 16.04 server that connects to MS SQL Server 2017 running on another server.

First, install the native MS ODBC driver "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server":

```
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server#ubuntu-1404-1604-and-1710
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql
apt-get install unixodbc-dev

# test you can actually get to port 1433 on the server that is running MS SQL:
nc -z -v -w5 host.where.sql.server.is.running.com 1433

# add /opt/mssql-tools/bin to your PATH in .bash_profile, e.g.:
# PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:$PATH"
# source ~/.bash_profile
# now, test that you can actually connect to MS SQL Server:
sqlcmd -S host.where.sql.server.is.running.com -U db_username -P db_password
```

Second, make sure you `pip install` these modules:

```
# https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure
django-pyodbc-azure==1.11.9.0

# https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki
pyodbc==4.0.22
```

Third, modify the DATABASES entry of your Django `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'db_username',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
        'HOST': 'host.where.sql.server.is.running.com',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'isolation_level': 'READ UNCOMMITTED',  # prevent SELECT deadlocks
        },
    },
}
```

I'm omitting the rest of my configuration (nginx, Gunicorn, Django REST Framework, etc), but that's outside the scope of this answer.

Update: this has been running in production for 6+ months now and hasn't had any issues beyond MS SQL Server-specific deadlocks when multiple connections are doing SELECT queries on the same table, which was fixed with the `isolation_level` setting.  The system gets about 2k new users every day.

Comment: @ianbroad - yes, this is still running in production, but it's still the same versions as I listed.  I haven't tried it on MacOS Mojave.

Comment: @ianbroad did you have to do some symlinks for libs. I am using the ODBC 17 driver but getting this error. Thanks

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading pyodbc module: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4):

We are using django-mssql in production at our company. We too had an existing system using mssql. For me personally it was the best design decision I have ever made because my productivity increased dramatically now that I can use django .

I submitted a patch but when I started using django-mssql and did a week or two of testing.Since then (October 2008) we run our system on django and it runs solid. I also tried pyodbc but I did not like to much.

We are running a repair system where all transactions run through this system 40 heavy users. If you have more questions let me know.

Comment: Is django-mssql tied to a particular version of django?

Comment: django-mssql requires django to be run on Windows.  What to do if one is running django on Linux?

Comment: @Paul, I have an existing sybase db that I want to connect Django to for select only reporting.  Can I connect directly to a DSN with django-mssql?

Answer (score 4):

I have seen so many people get the following error after installing `django_mssql` on Windows:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sqlserver_ado' isn't an available database backend.
Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
  'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named sqlserver_ado.base
```

The solution is installing the following plugin:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

Comment: I'm getting this exact error right now, the link is no longer valid, do you know where I can get the plugin?

Comment: @DavidZhanLiu: that's Python Win32 Extensions according to the web archive. It moved to http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used it in production yet, but my initial experiences with django-mssql have been pretty solid. All you need are the Python Win32 extensions and to get the sqlserver_ado module onto your Python path. From there, you just use `sql_server.pyodbc` as your `DATABASE_ENGINE`. So far I haven't noticed anything missing, but I haven't fully banged on it yet either.