# Django-mssql not found error

Tags: sql-server, django

I am trying to create a django app using my backend db as MSSQL. I am trying to use [this](http://django-mssql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) as the db engine. I used the settings as mentioned in the installation as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'texascompletes',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': 'dbserver\\ss2008',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',                     # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sqlserver_ado' isn't an available database backend.
Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
  'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named sqlserver_ado.base
```

I have followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10954946/1467535) and also installed the version that i use in my windows machine but the error still persists. What should i further look at to solve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842831/using-sql-server-with-django-in-production

Comment: can you check if the MSSQL python plugin has been installed properly?

Answer (score 1):

The current version of django-mssql supports Django 1.6. 
If using an older version of Django, you will need to use an earlier version of django-mssql.

django-mssql 1.4 supports Django 1.4 and 1.5.