# Using Sql Server with Django 2.0

Tags: python, sql-server, django, azure

I would like to use Django 2.0 with legacy MS SQL Server database.

Latest information regarding usage Django with MS SQL Server i could find is  [Using Sql Server with Django in production/These days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47029373/4636739) and it is about Django 1.11
Most supported seems [django-pyodbc-azure](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure) but it's not supporting Django 2.0 yet: 
[django-pyodbc-azure issue #124](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/issues/124)

Is there any alternative?

Comment: Would you please share your configuration and error trace?

Comment: I tried `pip install django-pyodbc-azure` but it want's to downgrade Django to 1.11, so I canceled it.

Comment: Would love to know how you resolve this... would rather not downgrade...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the solution and post it if anyone facing same problem.

I used [django-pyodbc-azure 2.0.4.1](https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/) in my Django 2.0.4

The settings that worked for me:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'dbName',
        'USER': 'yourUserName',
        'PASSWORD': 'yourPassword',
        'HOST': '(local)',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: good formatting on your answer. Welcome to StackOverflow buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same error of ODBC Driver Manager

*django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manag
er] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverCon
nect)')*

**Solution:** When i added below code in database connection, then my error fixed.

**'OPTIONS': {
         'host_is_server': True,
         'driver': 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server',
     }**