# How to connect remote SQL server with Django 2

Tags: python, sql-server, django, database-connection

I was trying to connect my **Django 2** project with a remote **SQL server** my connection string is

```
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        # 'ENGINE': 'django_pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'hrm5',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': '12345',
        'HOST': 'Remote Ip',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
```

I install *pyodbc-azure* & *django-mssql*
But still getting this error

> django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver
>   Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server' : file not
>   found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Also, I'm using Linux Mint-19 OS and SQL server -v is 12

Comment: How you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is solve [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112639/using-sql-server-with-django-2-0) using Django version 2.0.4 and its using this library [django-pyodbc-azure 2.0.4.1](https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/)

Comment: I just install pyodbc-azure and the error code change not getting solution still yet have a look my edit question